# Which cultivar is this purple Cattleya Aliance orchid?

Tags: identification, flowers, orchids, cultivar

[image]

This was a gift and does not have an ID tag! What is the name of this hybrid?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What a lovely flower you've brought us! I've done a quick search and haven't pinned it down, but I'm sure one of our more experienced orchid people will be along soon!

Comment: Thank you Sue. I am looking forward to hearing from the experts !!!

Answer (score 2):

Wow, this one was hard to pin down, but I think I got it:

*Cattleya Lc Gaskell-Pumila* x *Lc* 'Mini Purple'

Here are some comparison pics:

[image]

[<sup>source</sup>](http://www.outeniquaorchids.co.za/culturalnotes-cattleya.html)

[image]

[<sup>source</sup>](http://www7a.biglobe.ne.jp/~PAPHIO-IN-OKINAWA/kaiyouhakuC2.htm)